# How to remove ANIMATES in unwind segue in BOTH view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I have 2 view controllers in game iOS app. My NEXT button goes from VC1 to VC2 via unwind segue and a BACK button from VC2 to VC1. When I click on storyboard segue in attributes inspector in Xcode the NEXT button lights up. To get rid of animation from VC1 to VC 2 with NEXT button I unchecked Animates in Attributes Inspector. Now I need get rid of the Animation so its' also not present when I click BACK button from VC 2 to VC1.  (Using a MODAL segue)

My unwind segue code is in VC1:

```
-(IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{}
```

I tried the following code inside the IBAction code above...

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}]; //<-- Didn't even allow me to go to VC2 and I read to use this on StackOverflow.
```

What do I do to get rid of Animation that occurs between the transition of VC2 to VC1?

Comment: Your setup is somewhat confusing -- "My NEXT button goes from VC1 to VC2 via unwind segue", which sounds like you're going forward from VC1 to VC2 with an unwind (which would be wrong). Is that what you're doing? Is VC1 the initial VC?

Comment: VC1 is initial VC. the Segue code is in VC 1 ONLY. The returned button is the BACK button from VC 2 that goes to VC1.

Comment: So what kind of segue are you using to go from VC1 to VC2?

Comment: In my initiatel VC with the NEXT button I created a MODAL segue from NEXT button to VC2. Then in VC2 I dragged the BACK button into the EXIT and clicked on return Action Segue. My unwind segue works, that's not the issue. When I click the BACK button there is a split second animation between the transition of VC2 to VC1. I need to get rid of that animation. Don't know how.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to modify the animation of an unwind segue. Is there some reason, you don't just use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` to go back to VC1?

Comment: I've used that code inside the above IBAction segue code. What it does is once I click on NEXT button, for a split second, app shows me VC2 and then by itself goes back to VC1.

Comment: I mean to use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` in the button's action method **instead of** an unwind segue.

Comment: I don't use an IBAction method for this BACK button.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should use an IBAction for the button. Get rid of the segue, and call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` in the button's action method, passing NO for the animation parameter.

Comment: Is it wrong to keep the unwind segue while also use the BACK button with the IBAction as well?

Comment: Yes it is wrong. Both would be attempting to dismiss the same view controller.

Comment: I can't get rid of the unwind segue because my UIImageViews start to glitch in VC1 and iAd don't work at all even though I did shared banner integration. So I need to find a way to modify animation of unwind segue.

Comment: Did you try replacing the segue with he code? I don't see why it should make any difference which you use as far as any glitches are concerned.

Comment: The reason I used unwind segue was because I was having glitches in code. For some reason unwind segue would stop the glitches as opposed to a regular modal segue on both view controllers. Whether i'm adding your code in an IBAction or i'm just using a regular modal segue and unchecking Animates in attributes inspector, they both stop the animation that I wanted however, the glitches appear again and getting rid of glitches i've tried before, it takes a LOT of recoding of app.

Comment: Well, you certainly shouldn't have had modal segues on both controllers; you should never go back to a previous controller with anything other than an unwind segue (if you're using segues). If you still have that in there (the modal segue in VC2 going back to VC1), you should delete it. You may be out of luck trying to do what you are. You can change the animation of the unwind, I found out, but not turn it off. Changing it to a cross fade would more like no animation than the default one.

Comment: I'm using unwind segue. By changing animation of the unwind, are you referring to attributes inspector's transition?